# Does making question wiki discourage people from giving answers?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

i.e. - because they won't get any points for the answers?

Answer (score 10):

Not for me.  What discourages me from answering most wiki questions is the 30+ other answers already there.

Comment: + 1 - I will freely admit that I'm less likely to give a very detailed, long answer on a community wiki question. The 30+ other answers already there is definitely the primary motivator for being a little more terse in my answer, but the lack of reputation "payoff" is also a factor. I'm not going to bust my hump to give a really, really detailed answer "for nothing".

Answer (score 8):

I am less disposed to answer CW questions not because they are CW but for two other reasons:

1. The [200+ other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) in some cases; and
2. The high propensity for [fluff questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun).

Answer (score 4):

No.  Poorly worded, insulting, argumentative questions or questions with lots of answers already are the ones that don't get (more) answers.  I doubt if most people even look to see if the question is CW before answering.

Comment: Agreed. I typically don't notice if a post is Community Wiki until after I've submitted my answer. I'm not sure it would have made a difference (to me).

Comment: I would hope it doesn't make a difference, but I disappoint myself. I've answered questions and then seen it was community wiki, and it *felt* like a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it does play a role in the decision on whether to answer or not, especially when writing an answer would take a significant amount of time, yes.