# Why steal people effort by converting questions to community wiki?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

You automatically convert questions with more than 30 answers to CW (community wiki), then, reputation will not be given to the main person who made the answer.  I have seen answers with more than 300 upvotes for a person with 150 rep, he didn't profit from his effort because of this problem.  This may keep people from answering very common questions if they know this!

I am so sorry for the bad expression, but it is not fair IMHO!

For example:

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

The only fault of "Peter Majeed", "Jan Källman", "Panos" is that the question has 31 answers!!! it is not fair at all, for example the user [jan kallman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304193/jan-kallman) have only 151 rep, his answer has not changed by others, his answer has 138 up-votes only (1380 reps), he benefits only from 15 of them (150 reps only)!! if the question has 29 answers, he will benifits from them all, I think this should be mentioned seriously.

*** EDIT ***

I am not objecting to converting the questions to community wiki, I am objecting to not give the reputations to their owners!

Ok, what about this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-sharp-books

This has 20 answers, why the excel question's reputations gone out, but the c# book question got all of their reps?? they are both an off-topic questions!

What about this??

[Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age)

For example: Mike [Polen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age#1404) has 456 up-votes, he didn't got except a a little of them!!

*** EDIT ***

This is what @Pekka written:

> @Mohammad where is the effort in that question that's supposed to be
>   stolen away? What about that question should be worth thousands of
>   reputation points while actual good questions that people put hours or
>   days of effort in will usually gain 10 upvotes max?

This is the best answer IMHO, this has convinced me 100%!

Take this question and answers:

[Quadrilateral Shape Finding Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950983/quadrilateral-shape-finding-algorithm/14045103)

This questions are worth reputation and respect!  These answers won't take more than 250-400 reps with the bounty, although they worth more, but my previous examples wouldn't bring any rep compared with the last one!

Comment: Can you point out some example questions where that's a problem? In my experience, those questions usually are of the fluffy opinionated kind which is barely on-topic and shouldn't earn rep.

Comment: I have done that!

Comment: That is a "shopping list" type of question. Product recommendations are no longer considered constructive questions.

Comment: No, it is a serious question, I put my self instead of "jan kallman", I won't contribute to any of stack-exchange products if I see this!

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan It's an off-topic question of the shopping-list kind, where the answer's rep will mainly depend on the popularity of the product, and not on the quality of the answer. So IMO it's a good example for why this kind of question should be CW.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : Then the whole reputation system is wrong, this is not related to my question.

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan The reputation system is intended to reward high quality answers, not those that recommend a popular product. Yes, it's broken, but making your suggested change would break it even more.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thank you for deleting my comments :) I didn't suggest any changes, my suggestion is to give people there properties :)

Comment: 1) I can't delete your comments, and I don't think anybody else did. 2) You suggested disabling the mechanism that turns questions with many answers into a CW. That's a suggested change. 3) You used a bad question as example (off-topic shopping list), so you won't convince many to make that change.

Comment: Your second example is another subjective "what is best" question and the third one ("How do I calculate someone's age") had 3 years as a non CW question before getting converted on Aug 16 '11. The bike shed effect plus the fact it was posted by Jeff means the answerers there probably did very well out of it.

Comment: I am so sorry @CodesInChaos about saying that you are who deleted my comment! but I have presented two other examples!

Comment: Your second example is another shopping question. Your third example has a bit more merit. But Mike Polen certainly doesn't deserve 4000 reputation for an answer that was wrong for years.

Comment: when there really **is** a substantial effort put in some post, removing its CW status is dead easy. [Been there done that](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/remove-cw-status-for-this-answer-hashing-algorithms-testing-by-ian-boyd "an example")

Comment: @gnat - [And another example here on the famous RegEx question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121112/does-automatic-community-wiki-answers-discourage-more-responses?rq=1)

Comment: Have a look here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @CodesInChaos I intentionally put another "shopping question" question, but all the answers have got their complete reps, why?? because this question has less than 30 answers, but the first one's reps has been taken because the question has 31 answers, I think this is an inconsistency in the rep system.

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding it.  The reputation gain/loss stops applying *after* the post is CW, not *before*.

Comment: @Makoto I know that, but most of reps has been taken in the first question, you can make sure, I have investigated.

Comment: These questions are mostly historic artifacts. So people getting any reputation for them is a form of grandfathering. According to current standards they don't deserve any reputation, but since the standards were different back then, the rep isn't taken away. If you ask similar questions now, they get closed instantly.

Comment: Regarding Jan Källman's rep he/she has only ever posted two answers. Both of which were plugs for their EPPlus library.

Comment: I have edited my question, @Pekka has changed my mind with his comment!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why to steal people effort

What effort?

The example you show consists mainly of this sentence:

> What is the best tool for creating an Excel Spreadsheet with C#?

this took about 15 seconds to write down, and (no disrespect to the OP) didn't exactly take a genius to come up with. Why, in your opinion, should it be rewarded with 1800  reputation points?*

Show us a question that really cost some effort on the OP's part, or is a **great, clever question** in some other way, that has more than 30 answers. I predict most, if not all, questions you'll manage to come up with are "what is the best X" type kind of questions (which have become off-topic on SO in the meantime, btw).

<sub>* = theoretical because the daily reputation cap would prevent the OP from gaining the entire amount.</sub>

Comment: That's mainly an argument for per-post rep limits.

Comment: I have added a very obvious example!

Comment: @Mohammad I'm referring to that example. How is writing `What is the best tool for creating an Excel Spreadsheet with C#?` worth 1800 reputation points?

Comment: It may worth little less, but you can't take most of them!, there should be a more elegant way to prevent these cases.

Comment: @Mohammad I imagine the asker of that question got *plenty* of reputation. It took a long time for 30 answers to accumulate. All reputation before that, he got to keep. And one could make the argument *that* isn't fair. It's not much of a question really, is it?

Comment: That question will, hopefully, be deleted. It's just another broken window encouraging poor questions.

Comment: @Rosinante , My question, or the excel's one? :)

Comment: @Mohammed the Excel one.

Comment: @Pekka, It is actual and not theoretical, because the question asked 2 years ago, and they were not voted in a single day!

Comment: @Mohammad **where is the effort in that question that's supposed to be stolen away?** What about that question should be worth thousands of reputation points while actual *good* questions that people put hours or days of effort in will usually gain 10 upvotes max?

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan the excel question.

Comment: No offense intended but this post suggests Meta is the appropriate place to 'judge' reputation awards. "*How is writing What is the best tool for creating an Excel Spreadsheet with C#? worth 1800 reputation points?"* I understand the point of your statement (even agree with it) but I've always thought making those sorts of arguments was against the rules (noone can question votes: up or down unless malice was involved). Is that no longer true? Does that mean we can start comparing content:votes ratio? i.e. This question has 100 votes but its crap, compared to this thoughtful question w/5votes.

Comment: @Mike arguing about how much reputation questions should gain (if any), or even questioning the value of upvotes, has never been against any rules that I've ever heard of, and it's being done all the time on Meta. It would be a shame if we couldn't do that, wouldn't it? Comparing the content:votes ratio is fine, and an entire class of questions has been pushed off the site over the past year or two based on a judgement of questions' value... so don't hold back :)

Comment: @Pekka Fair-enough. I've always had it set in my mind that if you come to Meta looking to question a vote-count you would be shown the door in a brisk manner. I'll see if I can come up with some examples.

Comment: @Mike yeah, do! Of course, nobody can *change* the vote count on a question, no matter how much Meta discussion takes place. But we can bitch about *how it shouldn't have come to it* all we want. :)

Comment: I have edited my question, @Pekka has changed my mind with his comment on the question!

Answer (score 2):

The examples you've shown are questions that aren't a [good fit to the Q&A form](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq/#dontask).  For the most part, these questions are years old, and modern variations of them would be closed on sight.  See also:  [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

As to the "stealing effort" question - I **adamantly** disagree.  In fact, I feel that someone contributing to a CW does so for the benefit of knowledge to be shared and collaboratively built upon.  That's what Community Wikis are about.  Questions that make it up to that large answer count, regardless of how on/off topic the question is, do contain a wealth of knowledge, which helps the community overall in some respect.

While reputation is nice, it shouldn't be the end-all be all goal for recognition and effort.  If you're in it just for the rep, perhaps you're in it for the wrong reasons.

**EDIT:**  If you do feel that the answers there are worth some form of reward, then you can [attach a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/175248) to the question, and award one manually.

Comment: The reps are not everything, but they are the main thing makes SO the first IT questions site (As I think), It has a very strong system, but i think this is a problem in this system!! IMHO.

Comment: Reputation is fun, but gaining/contributing knowledge should be the overarching goal for users of the site.